# Why Lasso error increasing while update ? (+ evaluation)

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, lasso-regression

While Lasso updated, I checked MSE and the number of nonzero entries.

However, on every iteration, MSE increased, and the number of zeros of coefficients fluctuated according to the lambda.

So, my questions are :

1. On an every update iter., why the MSE increasing?
2. On an every update iter., can the number of zeros of coefficients be increasing or it be decreasing?

Plus, I found that on every update iter., the bigger lambda, the number of zeros increases, and the smaller lambda, the number of them decreases.

3. What's the general evaluation of Lasso?
   I thought MSE could also be used.

Finally, I uploaded several images below to understanding.

Thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: You might need to specify what you mean by LASSO update.

Comment: Generally, what is the problem you try to solve (I assume a linear regression with lasso regularization)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you're trying to fit a dataset where the features are denoted by `X` and the labels are denoted by `y`, with a model `f(X,w)`, where `w` are the parameters of the model.

LASSO will try to minimise the following objective function:

```
||y-f(X,w)||^2 + λ|w|_1
```

In this objective, `||y-f(X,w)||^2` denotes the sum of the squares of all the errors of the model, and `|w|_1` denotes the sum of all the components of `w`. So for large `λ`s, the model will try very hard to make `w` have many zero components, so that the overall `|w|_1` will be small. That explains why the number of zeros increases when lambda increases. If `λ` is smaller, the first term of the objective will be much more important, and so the model will focus on fixing errors.

Choosing the right `λ` value usually requires trying different possibilities and building different models on a different dataset than the training set (called validation set). For more about this, you should look up "cross validation" and "model selection".